# Problem with computing $\int{\frac{dx}{2\sin^2 x+3\cos^2 x}}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How computing this integral:

$$\int{\frac{dx}{2\sin^2 x+3\cos^2 x}}$$

I tried replace $\cos^2 x$ for $1-\sin^2 x$ and solve, but no sucess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your idea of replacing $\cos^2 x= 1 - \sin^2 x$. Then multiply by $1$ using $\sec^2 x/\sec^2 x$ to obtain
$$
\int \dfrac{\sec^2 x}{3\sec^2 x - \tan^2 x} \;dx
$$
Then use the $u$-sub of $u= \tan x$ and replace $\sec^2 x= \tan^2 x + 1$. This will give you
$$
\int \dfrac{du}{2u^2+3}
$$
This is handled the 'normal' way, multiplying by $3/3$ then rewriting the denominator as $(\sqrt{2}/3u)^2+1$. After, possibly another $u$-sub, you will find
$$
\int \dfrac{1}{2 \sin^2 x + 3 \cos^2 x} \;dx= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \arctan\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}} \tan x \right) + C
$$

Comment: This works better without the initial trig identity. Just divide by $\cos^2x$ in the very beginning.

Comment: in $\int{\frac{dx}{2u^2+3}}$ how get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$? i ever get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Cleaned up this is $\int \dfrac{1/3}{(\sqrt{2/3}u)^2+1}$. This gives $1/3 \arctan(\sqrt{2/3} u) \cdot \sqrt{3/2}+C$. But $3/\sqrt{3}=1/\sqrt{3}$ so that $1/\sqrt{2} \cdot 1/\sqrt{3}=1/\sqrt{6}$.